# ActiveMQ producer fails at times with "User producer is not authorized to create queue"

Tags: activemq-classic

Sometimes messages to working queues on ActiveMQ server aren't getting delivered. During failure we are seeing below stacktrace.

```
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: User producer is not authorized to create: queue://RO_EVENT_AND_OTHERS
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1393)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1319)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1967)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:288)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:223)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:95)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:66)
```

`activemq-security.xml`:

```xml
<plugins>
  <!-- Configure authentication; Username, passwords and groups -->
  <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
    <users>
      <authenticationUser username="admin" password="password" groups="users,admins"/>
      <authenticationUser username="consumer" password="${consumer.password}" groups="consumers"/>
      <authenticationUser username="producer" password="${producer.password}" groups="producers"/>
    </users>
  </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
  <!--  Lets configure a destination based authorization mechanism -->
  <authorizationPlugin>
    <map>
      <authorizationMap>
        <authorizationEntries>
          <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="consumers" write="producers" admin="admins"/>
          <authorizationEntry topic=">" read="consumers" write="producers" admin="admins"/>
          <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="consumers,producers" write="producers" admin="admins,producers,consumers"/>
        </authorizationEntries>
      </authorizationMap>
    </map>
  </authorizationPlugin>
</plugins>
```

`users.properties`

```
admin=admin
```

Comment: Is the user `producer` actually authorized to create `queue://RO_EVENT_AND_OTHERS`?

Comment: updated original post with security definition. producer isn't suppose to create queue. And more over the same user is able to send message after sometime

Comment: If the queue doesn't exist I believe the broker will attempt to create it on the user's behalf. Does the queue exist when the user `producer` gets this exception?

Comment: Yes, queue exist and for same user its able to send message at different time. I'm thinking tcp connection might be dropping off or maybe timeout issue.

Comment: How do you know the queue exists when this exception occurs?

Comment: I checked activemq management UI. Queue exists.

Comment: You should add all these details to the original question.

Comment: I have mentioned as working queue and i have also said message are getting delivered but its inconsistent.

Comment: Sure, but you said nothing about auto-creation and the steps to took to ensure it wasn't a problem.

Comment: I think if you were getting some kind of TCP error you'd have a different exception.